# Is custom entity mapping able to configure parent attributes?

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, orm, persistence

I'm working on a Framework that provides generated model. This model extends a class from this Framework.

```java
// Framework
Class Parent {
 private short version;
}

// Generated
Class Child extends Parent {
 private <type> attribute;
}
```

I would like to allow the user to activate optimistic-locking providing a custom entity-mapping. The *custom-orm-psql.xml* is linked via *persistence.xml*.

```xml
<entity class="package.Child" metadata-complete="false">
    <attributes>
        <version name="version" />
    </attributes>
</entity>
```

Can I change the parent attribute mapping because I'm not able to activate optimistic-locking?
It's working with `@Version` annotation on attribute `version`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could change Parent class definition for mapping. be sure that Parent class has the annotation  @MappedSuperclass on top of it. then the subclass can inherit all mapping info from Parent class.

Comment: My Parent class is @MappedSuperclass, but it does not work, version is never updated...